# Adding new data to multiple tables using dropdownlist

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

Using MVC4 am wanting to implement functionality which will allow a user to add new items to the database.

I've managed to achieve this adding items to a single table, but now I need to display data from multiple tables, then populate the added / selected data to those tables.

I have these 3 tables

**Threats**

- ID
- Description

**ThreatHasSecurityEvent**

- ThreatID
- SecurityEventID

**SecrutiyEvents**

- ID
- Description

And here's my code so far:

**ViewModel**

```
  public class ThreatWithSecurityEvents
    {
        public Threat Threat { get; set; }
        public SecurityEvent SecurityEvent { get; set; }
        public List<int> SecurityEventIds { get; set; }

        public ThreatWithSecurityEvents()
        {
            SecurityEventIds = new List<int>();
        }
    }
```

**Get Controller**

```
  [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult AddNewThreat()
        {
            ThreatWithSecurityEvents ViewModel = new ThreatWithSecurityEvents();
            var SecurityEvents = _DBContext.SecurityEvents.Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Text = x.Description,
                Value = x.ID.ToString()
            });
            ViewBag.SecurityEventDropdown = SecurityEvents;

            return View(ViewModel);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model  RiskAssesmentApplication.Models.ThreatWithSecurityEvents

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddNewThreat";
    //Layout = "~/Views/Shared/MasterLayout.cshtml";
}

<div style="font-family: Calibri">
<h2>AddNewThreat</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>Threat</legend>
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Add New Threat", "Threats"))
        {
        Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SecurityEventIds);
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => @Model.Threat.Description, "Threat Description")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => @Model.Threat.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => @Model.Threat.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => @Model.SecurityEvent.Description, "Associated Security Event")
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SecurityEventIds, ViewBag.SecurityEventDropdown as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Add New" />
        </p>
        }
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

    </div>
```

Am unsure how to implement the Post Action Method and a Save Method in the repository. 
Previously I could inject a new Threat Object and send it to the edit view doing something like:

**Previous Get Method - AddNewThreat**

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddNewThreat()
    {
        return View("EditThreat", new Threat());
    }
```

and I would then use the EditThreat Action Method to post back

**Previous Post Action - AddNewThreat**

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult EditThreat(Threat Threat)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                repository.SaveThreat(Threat);
                TempData["message"] = string.Format("{0} new description has been saved", Threat.Description);
                return RedirectToAction("GetThreat", new { ThreatID = Threat.ID });
            }
            else
            {
                // something is incorrect!
                return View(Threat);
            }
        }
```

**Previous Save Method - SaveThreat From Repository**

```
 public void SaveThreat(Threat Threat)
        {
            if (Threat.ID == 0)
            {
                _context.Threats.Add(Threat);
            }
            else
            {
                Threat dbEntry = _context.Threats.Find(Threat.ID);
                if (dbEntry != null)
                {
                    dbEntry.Description = Threat.Description;
                }
            }
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

That's as far as I have got so far.

I want the user to be able to enter a new threat description and then select a security event or multiple events from a drop down list which will be associated with the new threat.

I realize am going to have to change the post back action method in the controller and the Save method in my repository, but I cant work out how to get both the new Threat description and the existing security events saved back to the database. I've had a search but as of yet haven't found / understood anything.

Any advice/help would be great.

Thanks

Comment: First your need to remove `Html.HiddenFor(model => model.SecurityEventIds);` (you cant generate a hidden input for a complex objects or collection). Next use `@Html.ListBoxFor(x => x.SecurityEventIds, ViewBag.....)` so it generates a multiple select (i.e you can select one of more `SecrutiyEvents`). Then post back the model, save the new `Threat` and based on its new ID, save each selected `SecrutiyEvent` to the `ThreatHasSecurityEvent` table

Comment: Also your view model does not need `public SecurityEvent SecurityEvent { get; set; }`, but it should contain `int ThreatID` and `string Description` instead of `Threat Threat` and it should also include `public SelectList SecurityEventList { get; set; }` so you don't need to use `ViewBag`

Comment: Thanks Stephen, I haven't quite got it working yet but am getting there. I'll be sure to update.

Comment: Happy to post a detailed answer if you want.

Comment: Yes that would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You view model should be

```
public class NewThreatVM
{
  public string Description { get; set; } // add validation attributes as required
  public List<int> SelectedSecurityEvents { get; set; }
  public SelectList SecurityEventList { get; set; } // or IEnumerable<SelectListItem>
}
```

Side note: The `Threat.ID` property is not required in a create view, however if your want to use this for editing an existing `Threat` as well, add property `int? ID` and use `if (model.ID.HasValue)` in the POST method to determine if its a new or existing `Threat`

and the simplified view

```
@model yourAssembly.NewThreatVM
@Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Description)
  @Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.SelectedSecurityEvents, Model.SecurityEventList)
  <input type="Submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Side notes: Your view should not include a hidden input for the Security Event ID's (you cannot bind an input to a complex object or collection)

then the controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  NewThreatVM model = new NewThreatVM model();
  ConfigureViewModel(model);
  return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(NewThreatVM model)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    ConfigureViewModel(model);
    return View(model);
  }
  // Initialize new data model and map properties from view model
  Threat threat = new Threat() { Description = model.Description };
  // Save it (which will set its ID property)
  _context.Threats.Add(Threat);
  _context.SaveChanges();
  // Save each selected security event
  foreach (int selectedEvent in model.SelectedSecurityEvents)
  {
    ThreatHasSecurityEvent securityEvent = new ThreatHasSecurityEvent()
    {
      ThreatID = threat.ID,
      SecurityEventID = selectedEvent
    };
    _context.ThreatHasSecurityEvents.Add(securityEvent);
  }
  _context.SaveChanges();
  return RedirectToAction("GetThreat", new { ThreatID = threat.ID });
}

private void ConfigureViewModel(NewThreatVM model)
{
  var securityEvents = _context.SecurityEvents;
  model.SecurityEventList = new SelectList(securityEvents, "ID", "Description");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example and explanation, this has really helped, I was really stumped on how to pass back the view model and map it's properties to a new threat and then do the same with the security event. I was actual trying to map back to an instance of Security Event, I created a mess.. (face palm!!).

Answer (score 1):

I believe the easiest way to achieve this, is "dividing" your form into separated steps.

You have2 entities: Threats, SecurityEventID

Threat has a collection of SecurityEvents

---

1. Create a form to add/edit Threats (url: Threats/Add | Threats/Edit/ThreatId)
2. Create a form to add/delete Events of an existing Threat (url: Threats/AddEvent/ThreatIdHere

---

Use custom ViewModels instead of the original class to send data to controller. Examples:

```
public class AddThreatViewModel
{
   public string Description { get; set; }
   //since it's a add view model, we dont need a ThreatId here
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddThreat(AddThreatViewModel model)
{
    //convert the view model to Threat, add to database
}


public class AddThreatEvent
{
    public int ThreatId { get; set; }
    public int SecrutiyEventId { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddThreatEvent(AddThreatEventmodel)
{
    //add threat event into existing threat
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fabio, haven't quite got it working but will update when I have.